# Why is my rock paper scissors not working on the first click, the game works fine but the first click does nothing

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

As explained in the title, for some reason the first time you click it doesn't work but the second click goes through and the game works fine onwards, can anyone explain why? can't figure it out with my noob brain:

The game logic works perfectly fine, I know I've gone about it in a roundabout way but forgive me I'm still a noob and plan to keep iterating on this to make it more efficient.

Am I applying the styling to display the results in the wrong place or can you point me to why its not instantly starting the game?

```js
const pickIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('icons');
const pickWord = document.getElementsByClassName('word-choice');
const rockWord = document.getElementById('rock-word');
const paperWord = document.getElementById('paper-word');
const scissorsWord = document.getElementById('scissors-word');
// const resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');
let picksDisplay = document.getElementById('picks');
let resultDisplay = document.getElementById('winner-result');
let resultShow = document.getElementById('result-game');

let userPickIcon = ''
let userPick = ''
let compPick = ''

function playGame() {

  //player pick
  for (let i = 0; i < pickIcon.length; i++) {
    pickIcon[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block';
      if (pickIcon[i] === pickIcon[0] || pickIcon[i] === pickIcon[3]) {
        userPickIcon = 'rock'
        picksDisplay.innerText = `Player picked ${userPickIcon}`
      } else if (pickIcon[i] === pickIcon[1] || pickIcon[i] === pickIcon[4]) {
        userPickIcon = 'paper'
        picksDisplay.innerText = `Player picked ${userPickIcon}`
      } else if (pickIcon[i] === pickIcon[2] || pickIcon[i] === pickIcon[5]) {
        userPickIcon = 'scissors'
        picksDisplay.innerText = `Player picked ${userPickIcon}`
      }
    })
  }

  // computer randomised pick
  let computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  if (computerChoice === 0) {
    compPick = 'rock'
    resultDisplay.innerText = `Computer picked ${compPick}`
  } else if (computerChoice === 1) {
    compPick = 'paper'
    resultDisplay.innerText = `Computer picked ${compPick}`
  } else if (computerChoice === 2) {
    compPick = 'scissors'
    resultDisplay.innerText = `Computer picked ${compPick}`
  }

  //gamelogic
  if (userPickIcon === compPick) {
    resultShow.innerText = `The game is a tie!!!`
  } else {
    if (userPickIcon === 'rock') {
      if (compPick === 'paper') {
        resultShow.innerText = `Computer is the winner, Sorry :(`
      } else {
        resultShow.innerText = `The Player is the winner, Congratulations!!`
      }
    };

    if (userPickIcon === 'paper') {
      if (compPick === 'scissors') {
        resultShow.innerText = `Computer is the winner, Sorry :(`
      } else {
        resultShow.innerText = `The Player is the winner, Congratulations!!`
      }
    };

    if (userPickIcon === 'scissors') {
      if (compPick === 'rock') {
        resultShow.innerText = `Computer is the winner, Sorry :(`
      } else {
        resultShow.innerText = `The Player is the winner, Congratulations!!`
      }
    }
  }


}

document.addEventListener('click', playGame);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500&family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: #16213E;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 500px;
  color: #16213E;
}

.icons-div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

i {
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #277BC0;
}

i:hover {
  color: #1CD6CE;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.word-choice:hover {
  color: #1CD6CE;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.title-div {
  background-color: #277BC0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.results {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
}

.result-items {
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: #16213E;
}

#result-game {
  color: #495C83;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="title-div">
    <h2>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="choices-title">
    <h2>Make your choice</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="icons-div">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-hand-back-fist icons" id="rock-btn"></i></td>
        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-hand icons" id="paper-btn"></i></td>
        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-hand-scissors icons" id="scissors-btn"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h3 id="rock-word" class="word-choice icons">Rock</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3 id="paper-word" class="word-choice icons">Paper</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3 id="scissors-word" class="word-choice icons">Scissors</h3>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="results" id="result">
  <div class="result-items">
    <h3 id="picks"></h3>
    <h3 id="winner-result"></h3>
    <h2 id="result-game"></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are many things wrong here. First, you should not use a table for designing purposes. tables are for tabular data only! Then you should not use a for-loop to add an eventListener to a group of elements. Simply use `querySelectorAll` and `forEach`. Use switch statements instead of repeating if else

Comment: thanks for the input, will look to refine the code. still getting used to scoping my code so improving efficiency is kind of on the backburner for now. Now i got it working i can iterate and work on your above suggestions. much appreciated

Comment: I was new to the web stack too. Now I got a senior position and still can learn stuff. The one important thing I can give you as advice, skip what you do and follow the advice of more experienced developers. In many cases (such as this), many of the issues you are stuck with will resolve themself when following other methods. The main issue in your question is caused by many smaller issues (method-wise). So if you change the approach and work on efficiency now, you will properly already solve the issue without "wasting" to much time by fixing one the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated already in the comments, there are a lot of issues. I not going to fix every issue such as semantics and accessibility issues as this would blow the proportion of an answer (take it as a hint to read into it and work on it in the future).

1. You had a text and an icon that could be clicked. This means while you still have only 3 choices to make you had 6 elements that you could click on. This overcomplicated the necessary logic.  In other words, you had twice as many elements to check than necessary. I change it now that the `eventListener` listen to the container that contains an icon and the text.
2. You selected all the elements to check for the `eventListener` by using `getElementsByClassName`. This unfortunately returns an HTML Collection Object. As such you had to iterate through that object with a `for`-loop. This is highly inefficient and overcomplicated the issue as well. The smart and clean solution is to use `querySelectorAll` which will return a Node-List. The NodeList can be iterated with `forEach` which works faster and is shorter than a `for`-loop.
3. You nested a lot of `if/else`-statements. This is inefficient which a `switch`-statement and/or a ternary conditional operator can fix.

Now to the actual issue:
You have the entire logic running in a function. The `eventListener` is inside the function. So you have to click in your document first to run the function that then will start listing to the click events of the choices. That's why you need the extra click at the start.

If you programmed clean as described above you have the `EventListener` at the front and start the function when one of the choices is clicked on. That's what I meant in the comments, if you fix your major issues with your script performance-wise, the actual issue will resolve itself.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let playerChoice = e.currentTarget.id;
    let userPick = '';
    let computerPick = '';
    
    // Get User Pick
    switch (playerChoice) {
      case 'rock-btn':
        userPick = 'Rock';
        break;
      case 'paper-btn':
        userPick = 'Paper';
        break;
      case 'scissors-btn':
        userPick = 'Scissors';
        break;
    };
    document.querySelector('#picks').textContent = `Player picked ${userPick}`;
         
    // computer randomised pick 
    let computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    switch (computerChoice) {
      case 0:
        computerPick = 'Rock';
        break;
      case 1:
        computerPick = 'Paper';
        break;
      case 2:
        computerPick = 'Scissors';
        break;
    };
    document.querySelector('#winner-result').textContent = `Computer picked ${computerPick}`; 
    
    // game logic to check who wins;
    let result = '';
    if (userPick === computerPick) {
      result = 'draw';
    } else {
      switch (userPick) {
        case 'Rock':
          result = (computerPick === 'Scissors') ? 'win' : 'lose';
          break;
        case 'Paper':
          result = (computerPick === 'Rock') ? 'win' : 'lose';
          break;
        case 'Scissors':
          result = (computerPick === 'Paper') ? 'win' : 'lose';
          break;
       };
    };
    
    // output for winner
    let resultText = '';
    switch (result) {
      case 'draw':
        resultText = 'The game is a tie!!!';
        break;
      case 'win':
        resultText = 'The Player is the winner, Congratulations!!';
        break;
      case 'lose':
        resultText = 'The Computer is the winner, Sorry :(';
        break;
    };
    document.querySelector('#result-game').textContent = resultText;

    // makes the result box visible
    document.querySelector('#result').classList.remove('d-none');
  })
)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500&family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: #16213E;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 500px;
  color: #16213E;
}

.icons-div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

i {
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #277BC0;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.icons-div > button:hover,
.icons-div > button:hover i,
.icons-div > button:hover h3 {
  color: #1CD6CE;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.title-div {
  background-color: #277BC0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.results {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.result-items {
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: #16213E;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}

#result-game {
  color: #495C83;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="title-div">
    <h2>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="choices-title">
    <h2>Make your choice</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="icons-div">
    <button id="rock-btn">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-hand-back-fist icons"></i>
      <h3 class="word-choice icons">Rock</h3>
    </button>
    <button id="paper-btn">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-hand icons"></i>
      <h3 class="word-choice icons">Paper</h3>
    </button>
    <button id="scissors-btn">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-hand-scissors icons"></i>
      <h3 class="word-choice icons">Scissors</h3>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="results  d-none" id="result">
  <div class="result-items">
    <h3 id="picks"></h3>
    <h3 id="winner-result"></h3>
    <h2 id="result-game"></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You added an `eventListener` to the whole document:
 `document.addEventListener('click', playGame);`

Which then calls the function `playGame` if anything is clicked. `playGame` function adds the `eventListeners` to your rock, paper and scissors only after you made your first click that called `playGame`.

Comment: It was not advice. I described what his program is doing. And it is the issue, event listeners are added to rock, paper, scissor only after first click anywhere, thus 2 clicks needed

Comment: I'm very sorry, my previous rating was harsh and unfair. It took a while to understand what you actually mean. I made slight edits to your answer to correct formatting and grammar which made the answer clear.